# 。。。と言えば。。。だが construction, what does it mean?

Tags: grammar

I have found two sentences below, and I wonder whether it is some kind of grammatical construction or not.

```
理想といえば理想だが、頑張ればなんとかなるかもしれない。

公園といえば公園だが、狭いからあまり遊べないよ。
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> “Call it a dream, but...”
>
> “They call it a park, but...”

Is the corresponding construction in English. I believe I remembering covering this while studying for the JLPT N2, but there are websites covering most JLPT grammar points and all I’m turning up is the more common Xと言えば、Y form.

Comment: Could this be although?

Comment: Instead of “but”? Sure!